# background-color not stable in one position

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, slick.js

I'm customizing the look of Slick Slider.

I have a grey background I created on `.media-slider` that has a certain height and I position arrows to align with the top of the grey background:

Here is the grey background:

```
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eff3f5;
  display: block;
  height: 55.1%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I positioned the arrows like this:

```css
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-prev, .media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-next {
    background-color: #d4272e;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 54%;
}
```

This is the alignment I made where the top of the grey background aligns with the top of the arrow:

[image]

But this happens when i add more text to the p tag or change h1 to lower size h tags, The grey background is moving down as more or less content get added to the text.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue of aligning top of arrow and grey background around the center of the image?  I suspect I have to change the way I created the grey background.

Also on very small screen(iphone 5 screen size) i am getting this other slide pushing to the current slide like this, not sure if it caused by the same issue

[image]

Here is my full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".media-slider-bg-slide").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.media-slider-text-slider',
  });


  $(".media-slider-text-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    asNavFor: '.media-slider-bg-slide',
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    speed: 1000,
    arrows: true,
  });


});

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  function getImage() {
    jQuery(".media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap").each(function() {
      var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
    });
  }
  getImage();
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}

h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}

h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap {
  padding-top: 16%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-prev,
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-next {
  background-color: #d4272e;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 54%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-list {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-next {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-arrow:hover {
  background-color: #721722;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eff3f5;
  display: block;
  height: 55.1%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.media-slider-wrap .slick-prev:before,
.media-slider-wrap .slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top-center;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide div {
  height: 100%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-gradient-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-gradient-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* background-color: #000;
  */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#b3000000', GradientType=0);
}

.media-slider-wrap .pagingInfo {
  position: relative;
  left: 8rem;
  top: -10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="mt-5"></div>
<section class="media-slider-wrap">
  <div class="media-slider">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="media-slider-gradient-wrap">
        <div class="media-slider-bg-slide ">
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="media-slider-text-slider d-flex flex-wrap align-content-end  p-5">
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500sum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h2 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h3 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h5 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the change

```
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider:before {
/*  height: 55.1%; */
    /* The 100% height of every element 
       minus the top and bottom padding of .p-5 element
       times 54% which is the top value of 
       .media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-prev
       minus 1 Pixel due to rounding errors
    */
    top: calc((100% - 2 * 3rem) * .54 - 1px);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".media-slider-bg-slide").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.media-slider-text-slider',
  });


  $(".media-slider-text-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    asNavFor: '.media-slider-bg-slide',
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    speed: 1000,
    arrows: true,
  });


});

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  function getImage() {
    jQuery(".media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap").each(function() {
      var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
    });
  }
  getImage();
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}

h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}

h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap {
  padding-top: 16%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-prev,
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-next {
  background-color: #d4272e;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 54%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-list {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-next {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider .slick-arrow:hover {
  background-color: #721722;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eff3f5;
  display: block;
/*  height: 55.1%; */
  top: calc((100% - 2 * 3rem) * .54 - 1px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.media-slider-wrap .slick-prev:before,
.media-slider-wrap .slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top-center;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-img-wrap img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide div {
  height: 100%;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-gradient-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-gradient-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* background-color: #000;
  */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#b3000000', GradientType=0);
}

.media-slider-wrap .pagingInfo {
  position: relative;
  left: 8rem;
  top: -10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-bg-slide img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-wrap br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="mt-5"></div>
<section class="media-slider-wrap">
  <div class="media-slider">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="media-slider-gradient-wrap">
        <div class="media-slider-bg-slide ">
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1"></div>
          <div class="media-slider-img-wrap"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="media-slider-text-slider d-flex flex-wrap align-content-end  p-5">
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500sum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h2 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h3 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h5 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-slider-text-wrap">
                <h4> h4 Energy Delivered</h4>
                <p class="col-lg-6 pl-0">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="0">Learn More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is due to change in the height of meta slider.
i see you have positioned the buttons in percentage, 1% could mean many pixels on different scales and resolutions. if you want it pixel perfect, u can limit the height of meta slider in pixels. u can tweak this height in responsive dimensions as you like.

```
.media-slider-wrap .media-slider-text-slider {
    height: 566px;
}
```